Two player grid-based game, minimax not good, what to try?
In this game, a matrix with size N x M is given (10<=N,M<=15). There a three main type of value in the matrix:

A integer show how many gold is it
Char 'D' show obstacle
Char 'S' show shield (which can obtain to get through obstacle, once obtained can be used the whole match, there only 2 shield). Shield can not protect player when two players collide.
There are only two player. Player move simultaneously.
There're about 50 to 70 turn then the game will end.
There are chance treasure appear on the map (only once) with value 3/4 * d to 5/4 * d with d is the difference in gold of two player at that moment.

Find a way to maximize the gold. I've tried Minimax but it's seem not verry efficient. Is there any better approach to this problem?

Welcome to AI Stack Exchange. This looks on topic, but the title could be better. A good title is self-contained. So I'm going to attempt to rewrite it for you. If you don't like what I do,you can use [edit] to go back or improve it further

As a two-player game, what is the main objective? Maximimise total gold in colaboration, adding both players? For competing players, getting more gold than the other player, or getting the highest amount of gold possible (those are similar, but not the same objective)?

minmax in perfect information game is guaranteed to converge to a nash equilibrium if you are in a zero-sum games, but i can't see anything on the rewards/utilities
